# Variable from another agent in main

Tags: anylogic

I created an agent called Technician its a population and it has the variable capacity in boolean. The variable belongs to one agent (agent 0). In my main i have a button that changes its color if it is clicked on. The code i wrote for the Button in Fill color is.

```
technician.capacity==true? yellowGreen : tomato
```

It says that capacity cannot be resolved or is not a field

If i try technician with a T

```
Technician.capacity==true? yellowGreen : tomato
```

It says cannot make a reference to a non-static field

There must be wrong something with reference to technician part.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is in the Agent type, then every technician in your model has a `capacity` variable. For your code to work, you need to specify which technician you are referring to. Example: `technician.get(0).capacity`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an actual agent from the population so it would be something like this:

```
technicians(0).capacity==true? yellowGreen : tomato
```

Technician is the Agent Type...
by default variables are not static in an agent, and i won't go to what a static variable is... but Technician.capacity would work only if the capacity is static, which would means that capacity would have the same value for all agents in the population

if your population is not defined in plural then you need to do

```
technician(0).capacity==true? yellowGreen : tomato
```

Answer (score 0):

`Technician` is the type of the agent, the real agent is in the population `technician`.

If you wish to access a specific agent and check its parameter, you must do so by accessing the population.

```
technician.get(0).capacity
```